# I'm using Google Maps in React and my markers don't always load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

So as the title says, I'm using React and  trying to implement Google Maps with list of places fetched from Foursquare and display their markers. I'm not using any packages such as react-google-maps etc, just vanilla JS. The map loads just fine, the places are fetched BUT the markers show every now and then. When they do load, they point to correct location but they load rarely. I'm not sure what's wrong with my createMarkers function here:

```
// Initialize map   
initMap = () => {
    let map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: {lat: 45.5616873, lng: 18.6770196 }
    });

this.createMarkers(map);
}

// The following function uses the places array to create an array of markers on initialize.
createMarkers = (map) => {

    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.places.length; i++) {
      // Get the position from the location array
      let position = this.state.places[i].location;
      let name = this.state.places[i].name;
      let venueID = this.state.places[i].venueID;

      // Create a marker per location, and put into markers array.
      let marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        name: name,
        animation: window.google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: this.state.defaultIcon,
        venueID: venueID,
        map: map
      });

      // Set state to save the marker to our array of markers.
      this.setState((state) => ({
        markers: [...state.markers, marker]
      }))
    }
}

// Create default marker icon
makeMarkerIcon(markerColor) {
    const markerImage = new window.google.maps.Icon(
      'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=1.15|0|'+ markerColor +
      '|40|_|%E2%80%A2',
      new window.google.maps.Size(21, 34),
      new window.google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      new window.google.maps.Point(10, 34),
      new window.google.maps.Size(21,34)
      );
      return markerImage;
  };
```

Any help would be much appreciated, as I'm still new to React and prone to beginner's mistakes.

Comment: Are there any console errors?

Comment: No errors, everything seems to work correctly, minus the randomness of markers loading on every third refresh or so.

Comment: Can you confirm that the `createMarkers` function is being called on every refresh? Maybe add a `console.log` or something.

Comment: Interesting, so console.log I added at the end of this whole createMarkers function gets called on every refresh, but the one I added after let marker only gets called when markers are created. So apparently the marker variable isn't being created for some reason. Could it be cause I'm fetching from Foursquare?

Comment: I am not familiar with Foursquare so I can't help you there. Are you certain that the `this.state.places` array always contains data?